# How to add Air Pods to Find My on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, airpods, find-my-mac

Is it possible to add the Air Pods Pro headphones to the Find My app and devices in the Apple ID account on the MacBook? I've connected the headphones to the MacBook and can use them, but they won't show up in my devices in Apple ID and the Find My app, which is what I care about most. In both places I can only see the MacBook added, but the headphones do not. In the AirPods settings on the MacBook, I have "Find My" usage checked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the only solution is to connect them to the iPhone and then they should show up in Find My?

Comment: What macOS & what version AirPods? @Ruskes - Find My also works with AirPods, but not 1st gen, only 2nd & 3rd, Pro & Max. Also minimum macOS 13.

Comment: I'm using macOS 14.1 and AirPods 2 Pro

Comment: Have a look at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102648 - I can't test any of this, I don't have similar devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did everything from this page and I can see my Mac in the Find My app, but not the Air Pods. Unfortunately it looks like an iPhone is required to add AirPods to the Find My app.